# inheritance, protected. Crazy compiler

Tags: c++

```
class Rectangle{
public:
    Rectangle(double l=0.0, double w =0.0) : length(l), width(w){}
    double getLength() {return lenght;}
    double getWidth() { return width;}
    virtual double Area() { return length * height;}
protected:
    double length, width;

};
class Box : public Rectangle{
    public:
    // ERROR: compiler error on the next line:
    Box(double l, double w, double h) : length(l), width(w), height(h){}

    double getHeight() {return height;}
    double Volume();
    double Area(){
        return 6*length * width;
    }
    private:
    double height;
};
```

And I get a compile error on the marked line

```
Box(double l, double w, double h) : length(l), width(w), height(h){}
```

The compiler complains about that `class Box` doesnt have any field named `width`. What's the problem? Perhaps `length` is protected in the base class?

Comment: CE? What compiler error are you getting?

Comment: After all, I write:class Box doesnt have any field name width

Comment: The exact error, please.

Comment: damn those crazy compilers!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're blaming the compiler for your mistakes.

Comment: Shine On You Crazy Compiler.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 'cos the linker is too easy a target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have typo at the very beginning. You should change:

```
double getLength() {return lenght;}
```

with:

```
double getLength() {return length;}
//                             ^^
```

---

Secondly in your `Rectangle` class you are using an `height` identifier that you haven't declared in the class:

```
virtual double Area() { return length * height;}
```

---

Lastly, use the `Rectangle` constructor to initialize its member. So instead of:

```
Box(double l, double w, double h) : length(l), width(w), height(h){}
```

use:

```
Box(double l, double w, double h) : Rectangle(l, w), height(h){}
```

If you fix every error, your program will [compile just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1976840e0cd67f7f).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the Rectangle constructor, not the constuctors of Rectangles members!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize the members of base class in the initialization list. Use this

```
Box(double l, double w, double h) : Rectangle(l,w), height(h){}
```